# Função timer PHP

Tags: php

Alguém sabe alguma função de timer tipo o setTimeOut do javascript:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Só que em PHP?

Porque eu to tentando fazer com o Sleep, mas a página fica carregando infinitamente.

```
function Criar_Madeira($a) {
        $a->madeira += 500;
        sleep(10);
        Criar_Madeira($a);
}

Criar_Madeira($a[1]);
```

Comment: A sua função nunca termina porque você criou uma função com [recursividade](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursividade_(ciência_da_computação)). Não se esqueça que o PHP é uma linguagem server side, ou seja enquanto o seu script PHP não for concluído o utilizador irá ficar "sem" resposta do servidor.

Comment: Qual era o resultado que esperava atingir com um "timer" do lado do PHP ? Se a ideia é dar alguma temporização às ações que o usuário faz então é javascript que você quer usar.

Comment: Ou usa um processo em *background* acionado pela CRON.

Comment: Anderson, isso seria trocar o sleep por usleep, pq eu vi na net, fiz isso e continua carregando infintamente.

Answer (score 0):

PHP é *server-side*, portanto isso só pode ser feito no lado do cliente, no caso, javascript.

Comment: E JQuery, Angular, etc ?

Comment: Mas isso é pra um jogo, se tiver em client side será possível roubar...

Answer (score 0):

Você chamou a função dentro da função, e quando você faz isso, vai ficar dando um loop infinito, entende? Porque ela vai executar a mesma toda de novo, e vai acabar executando a parte que ela é chamada de novo rs.

```
function criarMadeira($a) { //Por que precisa desse parâmetro?
    sleep(10);  
    $this->madeira += 500;
}

criarMadeira(1); //Não entendi o porque desse valor 1
```

Lembre-se que o PHP funciona também em cascata, as coisas são executadas de cima pra baixo. Com o sleep antes, ele irá executar o `$this->madeira += 500;` só depois do mesmo.

Comment: É pra realmente ser um loop infinito, smpre ficar adicionando madeira.
Mas sem ficar carregando a página inifintamente.

Comment: Cara, assim a página vai travar... Sempre vai travar. É pra ser infinito mesmo?